# How to display a large amount of "edit users" panels?

Tags: website-design, web-app, hyperlinks, data-tables

I currently have got the following panel in my admin dashboard:
[image: The panel]

This is a panel where the admin can edit the users of the website.
It's currently made so that someone can click on it, and the link to the edit page will be shown:

[image: Animation]

But if there's a large amount of users, **how can I make a good UI out of this?** I don't want to have hundreds of blue panels...

I already thought about a "Search user" bar, which will only show up users that match with the search, but I don't know if that's a good way to do things either.

What are your suggestions?

Comment: What information on each user you want to edit? I mean name, birthday, email, etc?
Why not do it in place?
And do you need to edit bulk information (e.g. phone number of 50 users at once)?

Comment: @Mike No, you'll always have to only edit one user (and not a few of them simultaneously). If I click "edit", I get redirected to another page with A LOT of information I can see and edit, so I think it's better to have that on another page than to do it inline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd avoid creating the blue balloons in the first place.

You may use the initial message already - what if **Edit** in "Edit User Vincent" was already a link to editing facility? Or simply list all users (by name) and place the pencil icon (or **Edit** link) next to it. You are already in **Edit** page (header indicates it), no need to repeat information.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvbgDe.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

And instead redirecting to a separate web page open it in a modal window. You'll have the feeling of staying on the user list page.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMAnWa.png)</sup>

Comment: And can you give me a short graphical example on how you would design this list? I mean, there can be like 200 users, and I don't my page to consist of 90% "Edit users" panel :)

Comment: I've added two mockups. I hope that gives you the idea.

Comment: Especially the second mockup is really interesting, thank you!

Comment: Just a small addition to the first mockup. I used DRY rule there - don't repeat yourself. You are edition users - there's no need to place a link saying "edit" next to each user, just make a respective header. Also, no need to write "user" in front of each entry. There are only users in the list.